# Spring Boot @OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring Boot, and I'm a bit confused.

I created post and comment model, and I want post to have many comments.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name ="post_id")
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

And here is the comment:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private Post post;
```

So, I would like to have comments array when I return single post but due the error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException Cannot call sendError()`
,I had to set `@JsonIgnore` on comments getter.

What is the best practice for the mapping, how would I get the post comments, I guess, new http request is not recommended ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `@JoinColumn` on one object in relation and `mappedBy` on the second. Try to make it like that:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="post")
private List<Comment> comments;
```

in Post entity, and this in Comment entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private Post post;
```

`mappedBy` needs to store string with name of property in second entity. If your field storing infromation about post has name "post", then it has to be set as "post" to.

Answer (score 2):

You can also Configure `@JoinColumn` in your parent class (this line)

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

but you need to remove this entire code

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private Post post;
```

from your comment class. This kind of Mapping can used to avoid adding `@JsonIgnore` on comments getter.

Now you can easily save Post class with list of comments and also you get the post class with associated list of comments.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a pretty straight forward and simple case.

- Your **Post** class should look like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="post",
           cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Comment> comments;
```

The important part here is **mappedBy** it refers to the *post* property in the **Comment** class.

Bear in mind that having cascade set to ALL means that deleting a post will delete all the comments related to that post (which I assume is what you want).

- **Comment** class

With that out of the way, you can take care of your **Comment** class now, which will looks like this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="post_id")
private Post post;
```

The @JoinColumn refers to the column in the database which holds the id of the post the comments are related to, this is what makes the connection between the post and the comment.