# How to create with JPA foreignkey at 'One' side table OneToMany

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two class Employee and Email with relational OneToMany & ManyToOne.

How to create / generate with JPA table, foreignkey column ex:(email_id) at Employee table ?

[this is image ERD Table Employee(OneToMany) & Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQIA8.png)

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee {
@Id
private Long id;
private String name;
private String address;
@OneToMany
private List<Email> emailList;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Email {
@Id
private Long id;
private String email;
@ManyToOne
private Employee employee;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot @OneToMany mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915477/spring-boot-onetomany-mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design is incorrect, a foreign key should always be present on the `many` side in a `one to many` relationship. One employee can have many emails. `Many` is on the email side. One email is associated with one employee only.

Think about it, if an employee has many emails, how this will be presented in the table `Employee`? in the design provided, there will be duplicate entries for an employee with just the `email_id` which will be different.

But if it is the other way around, `employee_id` in the table `Email`. There will be multiple different entries for email and each entry will be associated with a specific employee.

Therefore `email_id` should not be present in `Employee` instead `employee_id` should be in the table `Email`.

Answer (score 0):

You add `@JoinColumn(name="employee _id", nullable=false)` in your `Email` class as:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee {
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
private List<Email> emailList;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Email {
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="employee_id", nullable=false)
private Employee employee;
}
```

**Nb : By design the foreign key will be present just in Email table**

If you would like to do this :
[image]

this is the code:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee {
...
OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "email_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Email email;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Email {
...
//remove this relationship
//@ManyToOne
//@JoinColumn(name="employee_id", nullable=false)
//private Employee employee;
}
```